# Why does the Profile popup link to the Voters tab?

Tags: discussion, user-card, votes-tab

When I hover my mouse over my name at the top of any page on Stack Overflow, a window like the following appears.

[image: Profile preview]

(By the way, what is this called?)

Why does **votes cast** link to the [Voters tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters) instead of the **Votes Cast** section of my profile? Aren't most people more interested in seeing their own voting history than searching for others'?

Comment: Yeah, given that all the other links point to the profile, it'd make sense to change that single one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's called exactly that, the "profile popup":

[image]

And I'd guess it's this way because there currently doesn't seem to be a user-specific Votes page, like there is for reputation, revisions, and favorites. You can only see a summary of your votes on your profile.